# Does KNN Imputation in R make use of rows that have all attributes or only some?

Tags: r, knn, imputation

I'm looking at the Pima Indian Dataset found in Kaggle.

I was thinking of imputing in order to add my own twist to projects I've found online but I'm not sure if my VIM::knn() function in R to impute is using the rows that has all attributes present or if it's also utilizing the rows that have only some attributes (fields) present (not NA).

Comment: I don't see a clear statement in the manual page. You might try contacting the `VIM` package maintainer. Load the package and use `maintainer("VIM")` to get the email address.

Comment: @dcarlson oh so this would be a question I'd ask the developers directly? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, since it is not clearly documented on the manual page (`?knn`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't provide a definitive answer, because it would take too long to check, but here is how you would check on your own.

Since it is open source, you can download the source code of the package on the CRAN page ([VIM CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VIM/index.html)). Here download the Package source:    **VIM_6.2.2.tar.gz** file.

Once you extracted it, you have the typical R package folder structure. You have to navigate to the folder /R and open the kNN.R file.

There you find the source code for the kNN function - looks like this:

```
kNN <- function(data, variable=colnames(data), metric=NULL, k=5, dist_var=colnames(data),weights=NULL,
                numFun = median, catFun=maxCat,
                makeNA=NULL,NAcond=NULL, impNA=TRUE, donorcond=NULL,mixed=vector(),mixed.constant=NULL,trace=FALSE,
                imp_var=TRUE,imp_suffix="imp", addRF=FALSE, onlyRF=FALSE,
                addRandom=FALSE,useImputedDist=TRUE,weightDist=FALSE,
                methodStand = "range",
                ordFun = medianSamp)
```

So everything in this function could be relevant.  It consists of several steps: input checks, considering weighting, a rather large part for Random Forest modeling of variables (to implement the addRF parameter), distance matrix, ... Unfortunately it is rather complicated to read, so you'd probably spend some time to figure out what all the parts are doing.